# Android studio gradle sync failed :constraintlayout-solver

Tags: android

I get the following error when running the app on Android
ERROR: Failed to resolve: constraintlayout-solver
Affected Modules: app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGo8b.png)
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fix the error adding a higher version of the ConstraintLayout dependency, as well as with higher `minSdkVersion` and then re-sync the project with `Gradle` again.

`implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"`.

For furhter reading take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).